# Can I use asynchronous Aalto-XML as JAXB implementation?

Tags: xml, kotlin, jaxb, spring-webflux

Is it possible to use aalto-xml as JAXB implementation?

I tried to pass AsyncXMLStreamReader to JAXB context:

```
val asyncInputFactory: AsyncXMLInputFactory = InputFactoryImpl()
asyncInputFactory.configureForSpeed()
val asyncStream = asyncInputFactory.createAsyncFor(xml.toByteArray())
return context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(asyncStream)
```

But it ended with error "reader must be on a START_ELEMENT event, not a 257 event"

Is there any way to use aalto with JAXB and not write low level xml parsing code?

Greetings,

Comment: Mind posting the XML? Maybe there is a problem? Code looks right.

Comment: @Damian, any update on this? Are you able to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting is related to async extension:

> AsyncXMLStreamReader.EVENT_INCOMPLETE (value 257; just outside range reserved by Stax API) is used to denote "not yet available" (without more data)

See https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml for more info

I am not aware of any JAXB implementation supporting async extension by default.